# Datetime picker shows LT at the end of date value instead of time

Tags: javascript, c#, momentjs

I use bootstrap and datetimepicker with momentjs in my frontend app.
In C# code the format is defined as

'''dateTimePickerOptions.format = $"{DateFormatHelper.GetJSFormat()}LT'''

So then I open my app in the frontend , click on datetimepicker it appears and shows date and time correctly, but when I click on a date in the calendar it shows a date plus LT at the end, for example, 01/10/2021LT
How to get rid of it LT at the end?

Comment: `LT'''` Umm, remove the `LT`?

Comment: What does `GetJSFormat` return?

Answer (score 1):

In your code LT is concatenate with your date statement you need to remove it

```
'''dateTimePickerOptions.format = $"{DateFormatHelper.GetJSFormat()}'''
```

confirm it's work for you or not !

Comment: The time should be displayed. It shows LT when i click on date. It should show date plus time not date plus LT. When the datetime picker appears it shows date and time correctly, only when I click on date it shows date plus LT. It also shows date and time correctly when I click twice on a date.